# get Document from a string stored in variable using Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Here is my code

```
  return await Firestore.instance.collection('RestaurantData').getDocuments('this.widget.restaurantName');
```

What should I place to access the passed data from the previous screen instead of **' this.widget.restaurantName'** to receive the document from **firebase in fluttter.**

Answer (score 2):

If you are passing data from one screen to another then you can do the following:

First Screen:

```
class FirstRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Route'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Open route'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute(resturantName : "Easy Meal")),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here we pass `resturantName` property to `SecondRoute`, then in the next Screen you can do:

```
class SecondRoute extends StatefulWidget {
    
  final String resturantName;
  SecondRoute({this.resturantName});
  
  @override
  _SecondRouteState createState() => _SecondRouteState();
}

class _SecondRouteState extends State<SecondRoute> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.resturantName),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

using `widget.resturantName` you can access the value in the next screen.

Comment: Actually this was what I wanted ```Firestore.instance.collection('RestaurantData').document('this.widget.restaurantName').snapshots(),``` I was already getting the name from previous screen that you are trying to tell. I just wanted to know the syntax for Firebase accessing of document

Comment: to retrieve a document then you have to do `Firestore.instance.collection('RestaurantData').document(this.widget.restaurantName).snapshots()` without quotations on `this.widget.restaurantName`